# Django query if field has chosen

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models : `ServiceRequest` and `Quote` like this:

```
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
   post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Quote(models.Model):
   service_request = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My question is: how to get `queryset` from `ServiceRequest` can know one of `Quote` has `status` is `True` ?

Example : `ServiceRequest` `id = 1` , have 2 `Quote`. One `status` is `True` and one is `False`.
`ServiceRequest` `id = 2` have 2 `Quote`, both them `status` is False.

I want `id=1` return True, and `id=2` return False

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try like this(using [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)):

```
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
   post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def current_quote_status(self):
      return self.quotes.filter(status=True).exists()

class Quote(models.Model):
   service_request = models.ForeignKey(ServiceRequest, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='quotes')
   status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Usage
ServiceRequest.objects.filter(quotes__status=True)

from django.db.models import F

ServiceRequest.objects.annotate(quote_status=F('quotes__status')).values('pk', 'quote_status')
# Output
# [{'pk': 1, 'quote_status': True}, {'pk': 1, 'quote_status': False}, {'pk': 2, 'quote_status': False}]]
```

#### Update

From comments, its better to have a property method to show the quote status:

```
class ServiceRequest(models.Model):
   post_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   @property
   def current_quote_status(self):
      return self.quotes.filter(status=True).exists()

# Usage

services = ServiceRequest.objects.all()
for s in services:
    print(s.current_quote_status)
```

### Update 2

Using [**`Subquery and OuterRef`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, Outerref

quotes = Quote.objects.filter(service_request=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('status')
services = ServiceRequest.objects.annotate(quote_status = Subquery(quotes.values('status')[:1]))
services.values('pk', 'quote_status')
```

Comment: it Return only `ServiceRequest` have quote status True. I want return both True False for other bussiness

Comment: @NgocPham how are you showing this in Django Rest Framework? (assuming from tags)

Comment: my result like your output. But It return multi `pk=1`. I want `quote_status ` `annotate` return True if one of `Quote` True, and False if all False. And `pk:1` in your comment must have status True.

Comment: @NgocPham please see the update section of the answer

Comment: yeah. It maybe answer i can accept. But i only want it is annotate because i dont need it appear everywhere in my project. I need it only in one filter `queryset`. So hard to create it with `annotate`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on whether there exists a related Quote with status True.

```
Quote.objects.filter(service_request_id=1, status=True).exists()
```

Comment: i only want query from `ServiceRequest`. Do you have anyway to do it ? I trying `annotate` but i cant finish create query.

Comment: What you mean, that i want to make query from `ServiceRequest` ?

Comment: yeah, i want it query from `ServiceRequest`. And better is one `annotate` field in it. Like `ServiceRequest.objects.all().annotate(has_status=....)...`

Comment: `ServiceRequest.objects.filter(quote__status=True)` Try this way.